# Flash message on unsuccessful 'create' not rendering for like / dislike function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have like and dislike buttons that are working, but the error message for voting more than once is not.

The object type that User can vote on is called Course. I'm listing all courses on courses index page along with their like/dislike buttons. I am trying to make it so if you try to like or dislike the same course object twice, the page renders a flash message informing you that you can only vote once.

Here is the controller for likes.

```
#likeables_controller.rb
class LikeablesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def create
    course = Course.find(params[:liked_id])
    count = course.likers.count
    current_user.like(course)
    new_count = course.likers.count
    if new_count > count
      redirect_to courses_url
    else
      # This isn't working
      flash[:danger] = "You can only vote on a course once!"
      redirect_to courses_url
    end
  end

  def destroy
    like = Likeable.find(params[:id])
    like.destroy
    redirect_to courses_url
  end

end
```

My courses index is rendering courses partial like so:

```
 # index.html.erb
<%= render @courses %>
```

The course partial in turn renders the like and dislike buttons

```
# _course.html.erb
<ul class="stats">
   <li>
      <%= render partial: 'dislike', locals: {course: course} %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= render partial: 'like', locals: {course: course} %>
    </li>
 </ul>

 # _like.html.erb
<%= form_for(current_user.likeables.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :liked_id, course.id %></div>
  <%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: "btn" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    <span id="likers"><%= course.likers.count %></span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And incase it's needed, here are the relevant parts of my models and schema:

```
create_table "dislikeables", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "disliker_id"
    t.integer  "disliked_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["disliked_id"], name: "index_dislikeables_on_disliked_id"
    t.index ["disliker_id", "disliked_id"], 
      name: "index_dislikeables_on_disliker_id_and_disliked_id", unique: true
    t.index ["disliker_id"], name: "index_dislikeables_on_disliker_id"
  end

  create_table "likeables", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "liker_id"
    t.integer  "liked_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["liked_id"], name: "index_likeables_on_liked_id"
    t.index ["liker_id", "liked_id"], 
      name: "index_likeables_on_liker_id_and_liked_id", unique: true
    t.index ["liker_id"], name: "index_likeables_on_liker_id"
  end
```

My models:

```
# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # User has many courses
  has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :likeables, foreign_key: "liker_id",
                       dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :likes, through: :likeables, source: :liked

  has_many :dislikeables, foreign_key: "disliker_id",
                       dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :dislikes, through: :dislikeables, source: :disliked

  def like(course)
    likes << course
  end

  def dislike(course)
    dislikes << course
  end

end

# course.rb
class Course < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :user

  has_many :likeables, foreign_key: "liked_id",
                       dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :likers, through: :likeables, source: :liker

  has_many :dislikeables, foreign_key: "disliked_id",
                       dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :dislikers, through: :dislikeables, source: :disliker

  def liker?(user)
    likes.include?(user)
  end

  def disliker?(user)
    dislikes.include?(user)
  end
end

# likeable.rb
class Likeable < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :liked, class_name: "Course"
  belongs_to :liker, class_name: "User"
  validates :liked_id, presence: true
  validates :liker_id, presence: true
end

# dislikeable.rb
class Dislikeable < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :disliked, class_name: "Course"
  belongs_to :disliker, class_name: "User"
  validates :disliked_id, presence: true
  validates :disliker_id, presence: true

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a problem in your action,

```
def create
  like = current_user.likes.where(liked_id: params[:liked_id]).first_or_initialize
  if like.new_record? && like.save
    redirect_to courses_url
  else
    redirect_to courses_url, flash: { danger: "You can only vote on a course once!" }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in controller try:

```
redirect_to courses_url, flash: { danger: "You can only vote on a course once!" }
```

And make sure in the application layout, you have the renderer for flash messages.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I checked and I am rendering flash messages in application layout. It may be because for some reason, likers count goes up no matter what within def create.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
redirect_to courses_url, alert:  "You can only vote on a course once!"
```